# Fill two columns with random dates

Tags: excel

I have to generate 10000 random dates in Excel. I found some website to do that, but the problem is I need fill out two columns ( pickup date, return date).
How can I coordinate between them where return date must be greater than pickup date?
Is there any website or functions in Excel to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `RANDBETWEEN` function to generate dates between a certain range e.g.:

```
 =RANDBETWEEN(DATE(2014,1,1),DATE(2014,1,26))
```

Then, in the second column, use the value in the first column as the date lower bound e.g.:

```
 =RANDBETWEEN(A1,DATE(2015,1,1))
```

Note that the output of `RANDBETWEEN` is a number that is Excel's underlying date representation, therefore you need to format the output cells as a date.

Comment: @user3236918 See the updated answer, probably the cell formatting just needs to be set to a date format. I just tried it in Excel 2013 windows and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom written script in Python, perl, or whatever you know or can learn, and create a [CSV file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). Import this CSV file into Excel. If you don't know how to program this might be a little too complex of a task, but this is the only direction of advice which is on-topic on this site.

If you need help post a new question with you attempt of a solution.